# How do you optimise Facebook Opengraph posts?

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-opengraph

I have an app that publishes events the user does to opengraph.  Of three different posts that account for the majority of impressions/conversion one of them is significantly more effective .

Would it be wise to remove the other 2 events and just stay with the most effective one so that is used more frequently.  These 3 events are probably posted within a 4 minute period for different triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Are they representing different actions? If so, removing 2 of the 3 will do nothing.

However, if they can all be used for the same action, then yes: remove the 2 poor performing one.

Comment: They represent different actions.  I guess the heart of the question is:
"Will the opengraph publish rate increase on the high performing event if I remove the other 2"